# v-navigation-drawer controlled state from a sub-component

Tags: vuetify.js

I have a [`v-navigation-drawer`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-navigation-drawer) which can be opened by clicking a button in a sub component.

So I changed `v-model="drawer"` to simply `value="drawer"` otherwise I get a warning about mutating a prop which makes sense (feels like doing some dirty angular double-way data binding ^^).

Here's the code:

`layouts/default.vue`:

```
<template>
    <Header :toggleLeftMenu="toggleLeftMenu" />
    <LeftMenu :show="showLeftMenu" :toggleLeftMenu="toggleLeftMenu" />
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        showLeftMenu: true,
      }
    },
    methods: {
      toggleLeftMenu() {
        this.showLeftMenu = !this.showLeftMenu;
      },
    }
  }
</script>
```

`components/layout/LeftMenu.vue`:

```
  <v-navigation-drawer
    :value="show"
    width="300"
    clipped
    fixed
    app
  >
```

This issue is that the drawer can be closed by clicking on the backdrop (on small devices). I need to plug the backdrop click to `toggleLeftMenu` prop, but according to the doc, this doesn't seem to be possible.

How can I achieve full control on the component? Is this @backdropClick event missing or something?

I tried to use `@input` but it creates an infinite loop which also makes sense.

Thanks

Using vuetify 2.6.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I changed `v-model="drawer"` to simply `value="drawer"` otherwise I get a warning about mutating a prop

This is not quite the right decision. Of course you should not use **drawer** as model, but you can create an **internalDrawer** prop in `LeftMenu` component, and leave the `v-model` where it is.

---

One of the possible ways to resolve your issue is **to emit events** from both sub-components into its parent.

So let's rewrite your `LeftMenu` component this way:

```js
<template>
  <v-navigation-drawer v-model="internalShow" width="200" clipped fixed app>
    some drawer data
  </v-navigation-drawer>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    show: Boolean,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      internalShow: this.show,
    };
  },
  watch: {
    show (val) {
      this.internalShow = val;
    },
    internalShow (val) {
      if (val !== this.show) {
        this.$emit("change-drawer-state");
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

In this case, every time when the **internalShow** state changes, an `change-drawer-state` event will be emitted.

Your `Header` component can be rewrited the same way:

```js
<template>
  <v-btn @click="$emit('change-drawer-state')">Drawer button</v-btn>
</template>
```

And this is the code of your parent component:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <Header @change-drawer-state="toggleLeftMenu" />
    <LeftMenu :show="showLeftMenu" @change-drawer-state="toggleLeftMenu" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import LeftMenu from "./LeftMenu";
import Header from "./Header";

export default {
  components: {
    LeftMenu,
    Header,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      showLeftMenu: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleLeftMenu() {
      this.showLeftMenu = !this.showLeftMenu;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Both `change-drawer-state` event handlers are calling the same method - **toggleLeftMenu** and then the method changes **show** prop of navigation-drawer.

You can test this solution [in a CodeSandbox playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-mahavira-whugz).

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for such complete answer! It works really well. I did not know how to deal with custom events with vue, and I'm always precautionary of using `watch` but this feels very neat!